# Hessian-vector products

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

Can someone explain why this is true?

$$g(x + \Delta x) = g(x) + H(x) \Delta x$$

where g is the gradient of function f(x) with respect to x, and H is the hessian of f(x) with respect to x.

I would really appreciate a detailed derivation because I don't understand what it means to take the gradient/derivative of $\Delta x$ which represents the change in x.

Source towards the top here: https://justindomke.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/hessian-vector-products/

Comment: Is it like the third term in the taylor expansion? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics)#Mappings_from_one_Euclidean_space_to_another

Comment: Is the lhs supposed to be the gradient taken at a point or is it a scalar? The hessian is a second order tensor, so it should eat two dx to become a scalar, not one, I believe.

Comment: $\Delta x$ is a vector I believe

Comment: I don't know why you're talking about scalars, the Hessian H(x) is a vector and so is $\Delta x$. Is it because the source link is $g(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$ is using scalar notation? He intends this to be the gradient of a vector

Comment: user3180: to know if there is an error and if so if it is on lhs or rhs (hessian is a second order tensor not a vector, according to some definitions, or maybe even third order tensor)

Comment: The formula $g(\Delta x)=H(x)\Delta x$ does not occur in the linked text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a scalar function f,

$f(x+dx) \approx f(x)+ \frac{d f(x)}{dx}* dx$

Vector case [$x$ is (n,1) dimensional vector]:

$g(x + \Delta x) \approx g(x) + g(\Delta x)$

$g(x) = \nabla f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
           g_1{(x)} \\
           g_2{(x)} \\
           \vdots \\
           g_n{(x)}
         \end{bmatrix}$ $\mid g_i{(x)} = \frac{\partial f(x)}{dx_i}$

$H(x) = \nabla g(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
\nabla g_1{(x)}^T \\
\nabla g_2{(x)}^T \\
\vdots \\
\nabla g_n{(x)}^T
\end{bmatrix}$

$g(x) +g(\Delta x) = g(x) + \Delta g(x)\approx g(x)+ \begin{bmatrix}
\nabla g_1{(x)}^T \Delta x \\
\nabla g_2{(x)}^T \Delta x\\
\vdots \\
\nabla g_n{(x)}^T \Delta x
\end{bmatrix}$

Translation: 
$g(\Delta x)$ represents g with a small change in x as input, which is equivalent to $\Delta g(x)$ [the infinitesimal change in g(x)].

If you look at the last column vector, you will see that each row $\nabla g_i(x)^T \Delta x$ represents the (rate of change of $g_i(x)$/rate of change of x) dotted with (infinitesimal change in x) := infinitesimal change in $g_i(x)$. In aggregate, the column vector represents the infinitesimal change in g(x) := $\Delta g(x)$.

See also: http://www.friesian.com/calculus.htm